# By default no Write permissions to package_data files

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

I would like to include certain user defined files such cfg.ini under package_data also with write permissions. But by default write permissions are disabled because I installed my package with sudo.

```
sudo python setup.install
```

By the way i am using setuptools to create my setup.py

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to this.

1. Install the package to the local user (instead of the system) by just using (without sudo):

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```

   This would allow the user to be able to edit the custom files.
2. As an alternative to having user defined files under the *package_data*, you could simply have user specific files generated in user specific directories which were read by your module. Then be edited by the user. On Windows this would be stored under the `AppData` directory for the user.

   The [appdirs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs/) package provides easy access to user directories for storing application data (it is MIT licensed).

   To install *appdirs* from PyPi:

   ```
   sudo pip install appdirs
   ```

   Or you can download the source, and then install it with:

   ```
   sudo python setup.py install
   ```

   Here's an example:

   ```
   >>> import appdirs
   >>> user_dir = appdirs.user_data_dir("YourAppOrModule", "YourName")
   >>> print(user_dir)
   C:\Users\TheUser\AppData\Local\YourName\YourAppOrModule
   ```

   And then you can generate the user files under `user_dir` and allow the user to edit them from there.